# Is communication with nearby (bluetooth?) devices (phones and tablets) possible considering the fact that they all share a same application?

Tags: android, ios, bluetooth

Consider an application that has for example application called "Covid detection". This application has a flag whether or not the owner of the device is covid infected at the moment. The user can change this. Now, let's assume a group of people having this same application.

My question is - is it possible for all devices to perform a scan every once a while to detect whether somebody in their close range was covid infected and send them a warning?

In my mind, the best possible scenario is to simply send a data over bluetooth everytime a bluetooth scan is performed, whitelisting the application as an auto-pair somehow (don't know if it's possible) and sharing user data (covid sick flag). However it seems like this is not possible, and instead the other way would be to perform the scan, save all MAC addresses of nearby devices and once internet connection is available, check the MAC addresses server-side for covid possibility.

Is this possible? Are there other ways?

Comment: Are you familiar with Bluetooth LE, "device" vs. "peripheral"and "advertising" vs. "scanning"? BLE advertising would be a way to make a device visible to others. Further again a "GATT Server" could provide additional data to other devices, but it feels like a bit heavy solution for this use case. With "BLE advertising" you could have some very simple payload in the advertisement package, maybe enough to identify your app and the user's Covid state(?) See [https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth-le](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth-le)

Comment: Btw, anything Covid related is under very heavy guidelines from Apple

Comment: Covid was just an example. The core idea revolves around something similiar.